# Icon appears on Google Play Store, but phones, it only shows the default icon?

Tags: android, google-play, coronasdk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLTu8.png)

This app was built in Corona SDK. Now, the icon appears perfectly fine in the Google Play Store, but I can't get it to work here. Is it because I did not upload a 32 bit image or my icon?

Comment: because you set the wrong image in your app. The icon in Google Play Store is different from your APK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have the correct icon filenames inside your project root as specified by [Corona guidelines](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/distribution/buildSettings/index.html#android):

Android

For Android, icon files will be copied into the .apk during the build, assuming they are available in your project folder. These icons should adhere to the standard Android icon names and sizes listed below.

File    Size (w×h)

Icon-xxxhdpi.png    192 × 192

Icon-xxhdpi.png 144 × 144

Icon-xhdpi.png  96 × 96

Icon-hdpi.png   72 × 72

Icon-mdpi.png   48 × 48

Icon-ldpi.png   36 × 36